# MySQL Insert into table with values from Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to insert data into a inventory table, pulling in a UserID from a separate Users table to populate one of the fields.;

```
 Inventory:
 ProductID | PurchasedByUser | OtherAttributes
```

and a table of Users;

```
 Users:
 DBID | UserActive | UserName
   1  |     1      |  mathew
```

So far my SQL looks like:

```
 INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductID, PurchasedByUser, OtherAttributes)
 SELECT 23, U.DBID, 'Yellow'
 FROM Inventory U INNER JOIN Users ud 
 ON U.DBID = ud.DBID AND ud.UserActive = 1 AND UserName = 'mathew'
```

Edit:
I want to be able to make a single SQL INSERT request to add
ProductID (INT), PurchasedByUser (Users.DBID), OtherAttributes (String) to the Inventory table without exposing the DBID and passing only the UserName field.

Comment: Why do you want to select from `Inventory`? And quote your static values like yellow and mathew.

Comment: What is 23 and what is yellow? And you mix SELECT with INSERT. This is a completely invalid query

Comment: @dimlucas you are not right => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I dont, this is just a sample SQL insert, Yellow represents $VariablesFromScript

Comment: Is 'Yellow' a string? Is 'mathew' [sic]?

Comment: @xAqweRx I'm not saying that it cannot be done, I'm saying that OP does it wrong and that in PHP it can be accomplished more elegantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHANGE U.DBID TO ud.DBID

```
INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductID, PurchasedByUser, OtherAttributes)
SELECT 23, ud.DBID, 'Yellow'
FROM Inventory U INNER JOIN Users ud 
ON U.PurchasedByUser = ud.DBID AND ud.UserActive = 1 AND ud.UserName = 'mathew';
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Query `U.DBID` is wrong because `U` is alias of Inventory so please change and put `ud.DBID` and your query will be resolve.

```
INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductID, PurchasedByUser, OtherAttributes)
SELECT 23, ud.DBID, Yellow
FROM Inventory U INNER JOIN Users ud 
ON U.PurchasedByUser = ud.DBID AND ud.UserActive = 1 AND ud.UserName = 'mathew'
```

Comment: `UserName = mathew` that's a string, not an integer.

Comment: Yes we must write  `ud.UserName = 'mathew'` because `mathew` is string and `UserName` is string type column.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL query you framed, you are referring to DBID of U which is the Inventory table. From the structure you shared, I think you want the following query:

```
 INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductID, PurchasedByUser, OtherAttributes)
 SELECT 23, ud.DBID, Yellow
 FROM Inventory U INNER JOIN Users ud 
 ON U.PurchasedByUser= ud.DBID AND ud.UserActive = 1 AND UserName = 'mathew'
```

I'm still confused with what are trying to achieve here, you are fetching values from the Inventory and inserting it back again.. Not sure about that.. Just trying to help you figure out the query!

Comment: `UserName = mathew` that's a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that in a two-step process. First get the id of the user:

```
SELECT DBID
FROM Users
WHERE UserActive=1 AND UserName='mathew';
```

Now that you have the user's id you can insert it into the `Inventory` table with a second query:

```
INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductID,PurchasedByUser,OtherAttributes )
VALUES(23,<THE-USER'S-ID>, 'Yellow');
```

I assume you know how to do this in PHP because you're not asking for PHP code

Answer (score 0):

I believe `23` & `Yellow` are records And you need a `quote` for `mathew`.

```
  INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductID, PurchasedByUser, OtherAttributes)
  SELECT 23, U.DBID, Yellow
  FROM Inventory U INNER JOIN Users ud 
  ON U.DBID = ud.DBID AND ud.UserActive = 1 AND UserName = mathew
```

To This

```
 INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductID, PurchasedByUser, OtherAttributes)
 SELECT ProductID, PurchasedByUser , OtherAttributes
 FROM Inventory U INNER JOIN Users ud 
 ON U.DBID = ud.DBID AND ud.UserActive = 1 AND UserName = 'mathew'
```